# Is the following a good way to understand bindigs on lisp?

Tags: scheme, lisp

Lately I have been learning lisp (scheme to be specific) and I would like to know if I understood correctly the concept of binding. So could anyone tell me if the following idea / analogy is correct?

"Binding are like string that connect symbols with values and the scope is the part of the program for which the computer keeps each of these strings connected"

Comment: It's useful to distinguish between **scope**, which tells you *where* a binding is visible, and **extent** which tells you *when* it is visible.

Comment: Since "string" is used for "character string", it's really best to use another word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's generally pretty good. Your last sentence looks like it has a hint of a "time" idea in your use of the word "keeps", and I would try to get rid of that.

I think I might say that a binding is an association between a name and a value, and its scope is the region of the program in which that binding is valid.

It's very hard to define a notion of binding independently of a specific binding form.

So, for instance, in math you might write

```
f(x) = 3x + 4
g(y) = 6y + 9
```

... but you probably wouldn't write

```
f(x) = 3x + 4
g(y) = 6x + 9
```

... because there's no binding for `x` in the body of the function `g`.